# How to synchronize SerialPort operations?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, serial-port, synchronization

I have an application that communicates with a microcontroller via serial port. I want to check the controller's status periodically in a Background Worker, and also allow the user to interact with the controller asynchronously (via user interface), by sending commands and receiving responses.

The UI and Background Worker use the SerialCommunication static class:

```
static class SerialCommunication
{
    static SerialPort serialPort;
    static int readWriteTimeout = 1000; // [ms]
    static int waitForTransmissionTimeout = 2; // [s]
    static string rxData = "", endOfString = "" + char.MinValue;
    static bool WaitingForSerialData = false; // Set in SerialWrite(), cleared in SerialRead()

    [...]
    public static string SerialRead()
    {
        try
        {
            rxData = serialPort.ReadTo(endOfString);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            WaitingForSerialData = false;
            throw new Exception(Properties.Resources.serial_read_timeout);
        }
        WaitingForSerialData = false;
        return rxData;
    }

    public static void SerialWrite(string text)
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        while (WaitingForSerialData) // Avoids the situation in which a command executed on a thread receives the response for the command executed from a different thread
        {
            if (!WaitingForSerialData)
            {
                try
                {
                    WaitingForSerialData = true; // All commands wait for confirmation/data, so it is normal to set this boolean value for every serial transmission
                    serialPort.Write(text);
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    throw new Exception(Properties.Resources.serial_write_timeout);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                if ((DateTime.Now - start).Seconds >= waitForTransmissionTimeout)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Timeout");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The serial port is initialized at application startup. `SerialWrite` and `SerialRead` are called in the UI or Background Worker consecutively.

I want to avoid situations in which a command receives the response from another command executed in a different thread. Currently, I've implemented waiting in SerialWrite for the command to be received (for SerialRead to finish) before sending the command, but I'm afraid that this can block the UI (for up to `waitForTransmissionTimeout` seconds), if SerialWrite is executed from there.

**So what is the best way to synchronize the SerialPort operations?**

Comment: So, _all_ commands are SerialWrite followed by SerialRead to receive response? If so, why don't you combine read and write operations in single SendCommand or something?

Comment: @Evk But what will happen if the SendCommand is executed, for example, in the Background Worker thread, and immediately after (before it finished execution) in the UI?

Comment: You should protect whole operation (write + followed read) by simple lock. Then if UI sends command before background worker finished executing - it will wait until it's done. Of course you should not execute that operation from UI thread anyway. Execute it from background thread, then dispatch result back to UI thread when done (to show user the result). Never execute such things on UI thread directly.

Comment: @Evk Can you, please, give a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the whole situation, but it seems to me you can just use a simple lock to serialize your write followed by read, like this:

```
static class SerialCommunication
{
    static SerialPort serialPort;
    static string endOfString = "" + char.MinValue;
    static readonly object _commandLock = new object();

    public static string SendCommand(string text) {
        lock (_commandLock) {
            SerialWrite(text);
            return SerialRead();
        }
    }

    private static string SerialRead() {
        try {
            return serialPort.ReadTo(endOfString);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException) {
            throw new Exception(Properties.Resources.serial_read_timeout);
        }            
    }

    private static void SerialWrite(string text) {
        try {
            serialPort.Write(text);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException) {
            throw new Exception(Properties.Resources.serial_write_timeout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Regarding the UI, should I use a Background Worker for serial operations, or is there a solution to write a more compact code?

Comment: You can use background thread, or use Task.Run, or use async\await if your version of C# compiler supports that. You can read about this in many places - for example https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/14/using-async-and-await-to-update-the-ui-thread/.

Comment: I've tested this method and got the following exception: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. I have a background worker that every 2 seconds checks the system's status and the user can command the system from the GUI. The error appears sometimes when the user issues a command (which is also executed in a background worker). **Why does the lock method not work?**

Comment: @CristianM I really doubt this error is related to the code you provided. Maybe you have to ask new question and post code you have so far, with exception stack trace etc.